# Download p12 file from firebase

Tags: firebase, p12

can I ask ...how to download p12 certificate from firebase ?
because I want to implement push notification on my own notification manager with that certificate

Answer (score 0):

Optional. Editor Setup for restricted access.
If you choose to use rules that disallow public access, you will need to configure the SDK to use a service account to run in the Unity Editor. This will also allow you to impersonate end users while testing. To do this first create a new p12 file via

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project?project=YOUR-FIREBASE-APP